# Bluetooth is not working in Kubuntu 21.10, but works in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, bluetooth, 21.10

**If you are facing the similar issue, I have added how I solved it simply at the end of the description.**

I have Kubuntu dual-booted with Windows 10. In windows 10 partition, Bluetooth is working perfectly. But in Kubuntu partition, Bluetooth manager keeps searching for devices but never finds any. The computer itself is also not visible from other devices like my phone.

I tried all the solutions I could find online like restarting Bluetooth downloading Bluetooth manager and such but nothing seem to work.

Please help.

Edit:

I ran this:

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb

This is the output:

```
> 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
> ?BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
>         DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
>         Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n >[103c:2230]
>         Kernel driver in use: wl Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device Bus 001 Device 003: ID
> 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam Bus
> 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 003
> Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 002 Device
> 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless
> rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
> 
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**How I Solved the issue:**

I downloaded https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases the deb file from this link, installed it, rebooted and it is fixed now.

https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware this is the repository of the firmware.

You will find the details there. It is for them who have broadcom Bluetooth hardware ranging from BCM20702, BCM20703, BCM43142 chipsets and other.

You will find your version by running the first command that a ran. From this output:

> DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0
> combo adapter

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I have, could you please take another look. @Pilot6

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you very much. @Pilot6